# How to eliminate a rails n+1 query that uses an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, activerecord

I have an n+1 query that I would like to eliminate. I use eager loading in a private method, `settlements_by_user`, to load a settlement along with pay period, provider account, and associated user. However I am noticing that my `group_by` method is creating an n+1 situation. The block given to `group_by` is an association, and for each settlement it is firing a DB query to find the user. Why is a query being fired when the users should already be pre-loaded?

Below is my Settlement model with its association:

```
class Settlement < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user, through: :pay_period
```

And here is the eager loading AR query, as well as the n+1 created by `group_by` given the `user` association as a block.

```
  def build
    @data = {}
    settlements_by_user.group_by(&:user).each do |user, user_settlements|
      (@data[user.id] = {
        user: user,
        settlements: user_settlements
      })
    end
    self
  end

  private

  def settlements_by_user
    settlements = Settlement.unprocessed.positive.where('date(settlements.created_at) = ?', settlements_created_on).
      order(total_amount_cents: :desc).
      eager_load(pay_period: { provider_account: :user })
    settlements
  end
```

Comment: Have you tried updating your eager_load to something like `eager_load(:user)` - rails may be resolving the relation to user from settlement separately from the one you've put in

Answer (score 0):

As naveed suggested the way the eager load was written wasn't resolving the relation from settlement to user correctly. Changing it to simply `eager_load(:user)` solved my n+1 problem!